# AppInviteDialog doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send an invitation to my friend. this invitation is for download my app from the playstore.
the app link Url is provided by facebook.
I use facebook-android-sdk 4.5 
Here is my Android code

```
            if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
                AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                        .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                        .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                        .build();

                AppInviteDialog.show(getActivity(), content);
            }
```

The facebook Dialog is open, i select my friends, i click on send button and everything is cool. but my friends dont receive any invitation, notification or message
my facebook app is in production.
I dont receive any exception or something.